# Ada Return Concatenated String of Strings

Tags: string, types, concatenation, record, ada

I am trying to finish up a homework assignment, and am down to the last part.  First, I'll show you the type that I am dealing with:

```
TYPE Book_Collection IS
  RECORD
     Books        : Book_Collection_Array;
     Max_Size     : Integer;
     Size : Integer;
  END RECORD;

TYPE Book_Type IS
  RECORD
     Title,
     Author,
     Publisher : Title_Str;
     Year      : Year_Type;
     Edition   : Natural;
     Isbn      : Isbn_Type;
     Price     : Dollars;
     Stock     : Natural;
     Format    : Format_Type;
  END RECORD;
```

Book_Collection_Array is an array of book_type.  These are private types, so the array is bounded (1..200).

There is a function called ToString in a separate package that was provided to us, that takes a book_type as input, and returns a string of all the elements of book_type.  What I need to create is a function that takes book_collection is a parameter, and returns a string concatenating all of the strings that are returned by the ToString function that was provided, for the book_types that exist in that book_collection.  I have made multiple attempts, but am constantly getting range check failures.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

***Edit:
Thank you to both of you for your help.  I went the route of using an unbounded string, and appending each string to it, then declaring an output string and setting it as a constant string equal to the the To_String of the unbounded_string.***

Comment: Another Hint: Ada.Strings.Unbounded. Which is a different way of doing it to what @T.E.D. suggests.

Comment: Yes. If you really *must* use your C/Java idioms of progressively building a string into the same variable over a series of steps, it's much easier to use Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String, which acts like a Java-style string (or C++ std::string).

Comment: @T.E.D., given that there may be up to 200 strings to catenate in this bizarre piece of homework, I think Unbounded has to be the way to go. I do wonder what Title_Str (used in Book_Type) looks like.

Comment: @SimonWright - True. If catenation needs doing in a loop, the constant string approach will typically require you to implement the loop via recursion. Many of us wouldn't think twice about that, but its a bit much to expect out of a CS student.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  Titile_Str is: SUBTYPE  Title_Str IS String(1..30);

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you a hint.

Ada strings ideally aren't treated or handled much like C or Java strings at all. C strings count on a trailing nul (0) character to designate the end of data in a buffer. Java strings keep track of their own length, and will dynamically reallocate themselves to keep to the proper length if need be. So typical string-handling idioms in those languages think nothing of progressively modifying a string variable.

Ada strings instead are expected to be **perfectly-sized** when created. Most routines will assume that every element in a string array contains valid character data, and any destination string you assign data into will be perfectly sized to hold it. If that isn't the case, usually an exception is raised (and most likely your program crashes).

There are several ways to deal with this when you are building a string. One way is to create a really big string object as a buffer, and keep a separate length variable to tell your code how much data is really in there at all times. Then when you call Ada string routines you can feed them just the slice of data from the string that is valid. eg: `Put_line (My_New_String(1..My_String_Length));`

A better way is to just deal with perfectly-sized constant strings. For example, if you want to tack `String1` and `String2` together, the safe Ada way to do this is:

```
My_New_String : constant String := String1 & String2;
```

Then if you later want a string that is this string with `String3` tacked on:

```
My_New_New_String : constant String := My_New_String & String3;
```

For more info on this, I suggest you look at some of the links over on the right side of this browser window under the heading "Related". I see a lot of good stuff in there.